# How do I assign variables in one statement?

Tags: css, less

I am using CSS Less for my project, I have a problem to write the following CSS into Less.

Here `color` is same for `.btn` and `.header` but how can I simplify using Less?

### variable

```
@whiteColor: #fff;
```

### CSS

```
.btn{    
    border: none;    
    color: #ffffff;    
}
.header{
    color:#fff;
}
```

I have written in the following way. **Is there any way to write it in only one statement?**

```
.btn{    
    border: none;    
    color: @whiteColor;    
}
.header{
    background:@whiteColor;
}
```

Comment: if it were same attributes then possibly we could do. `.btn .header {color: @whiteColor}` But here we have `color` and `background`

Comment: Are you trying to set same value for `color` (as in your CSS code) or `color` for one and `background` for another? If former, you don't even need Less and even CSS selector grouping should be enough. If latter, even Less cannot help you write it in only one line.

Comment: @mmvsbg: Please do not make code edits that change the original intent of the author. Here you had changed `color` to `background` (and my mistake, I had approved it wrongly too).

Comment: @Harry Interesting, I do not recall changing color to background, although looking at the edit log shows that change made by me. I'm a bit baffled and perplexed by that but totally possible that I've somehow made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the property to which the value needs to be assigned is the same (`color`), you can do it using a single statement by [**grouping selectors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#grouping). Below is a sample snippet:

```css
@whiteColor: #fff;
.btn{    
  border: none;    
}
.btn, 
.header{ /* selector grouping */
  color: @whiteColor;
}
```

Note that you **don't even need Less** for the above if the `color` is not going to change often. I would assume this is the case because of how closely the variable name is coupled to the color and in that case you can use pure CSS like in the below snippet.

```css
.btn {
  border: none;
}
.btn,
.header { /* selector grouping */
  color: #fff;
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='btn'>Some button</div>
<div class='header'>Some header</div>
```

---

If the properties are different (one has white as its `color` while the other has it as `background`), then it cannot be simplified into a single line even while using Less.

You can use a [parametric mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature) and [property name interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-properties) like in the below snippets but these only **complicate the situation** than simplify it.

```css
/* If color is same but property is different */

@whiteColor: #fff;
.apply-white-color(@property){
  &{
    @{property}: @whiteColor;
  }
}
.btn{    
  border: none;    
  .apply-white-color(color); /* the property to which white color should applied is passed as parameter */
}
.header{
  .apply-white-color(background);    
}
```

```css
/* If property is same but color is different */
@whiteColor: #fff;
@redColor: #f00;
.apply-color(@value){
  &{
   color: @value;
  }
}
.btn{    
  border: none;    
  .apply-color(@whiteColor); /* the color which should applied is passed as parameter */
}
.header{
  .apply-color(@redColor);    
}
```